# Woocommerce version issue with custom payment gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, woothemes

- for WC version(2.5.3) I see blank page when i go to

  *WooCommerce --> Settings --> Checkout*

I created custom payment gateway for WC and its working great with WC version 2.5.3  so,for this version in admin-side when I go to checkout tab and hover over my custom payment gateway it's show me link like this

```
http://localhost/demo_site/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout&section=**wc_xy_payment_gateway**
```

now I update WC to 2.6 and again go to same page it's will generate different link like..

```
http://localhost/demo_site/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout&section=**wc_xy**
```

I don't understand why this happening, even I didn't make any changes in code

Comment: @LoicTheAztec . i extends "WC_Payment_Gateway" class of woocommerce.and i defined some useful info on "plugins_loaded" hook using https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/ this link. again i remind you that its working fine with older version of WC

Comment: i troubleshot the issue and find that its because of **this->id='xy'**. when i changed this payment ID  to somethings else its started working. anyone have idea why this happening ?